# What is the right way to use len() *inside* a class?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I'm trying to figure out how `len()` is works when used *inside* Python class. Running this code results in the error shown, even though I added a `__len__` overload and used `@property`, following various advice from the Internet.

```
class Routes:
   def __init__(self):
      self._route_list = list()

   def __len__(self):
      return len(self._route_list)

   @property
   def route_list(self):
      return self._route_list

   @classmethod
   def check_list(self):
      if not self.route_list or len(self.route_list) == 0:
         print('ERROR: no items to print!')

routes = Routes()
routes.check_list()
```

```
TypeError: object of type 'property' has no len()
```

Comment: The "problem" is the ``@classmethod`` decorator - remove it and your code will work. Why did you make the method a class method in the first place? Only the class instance can access ``_route_list``

Comment: Also, looks like in your if clause `not self.route_list` and `len(self.route_list) == 0` are checking the same thing.

Comment: @MikeScotty I though `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` are like non-static and static methods in C. It seems like theses two decorators are both variations of static method, and their absence means that the method is non-static.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Routes:
   def __init__(self):
      self._route_list = list()

   def __len__(self):
      return len(self._route_list)

   def add_route(self):
    self._route_list.append("route")

routes = Routes()
print(len(routes)) # 0
routes.add_route()
print(len(routes)) # 1
```

When you override len, you are overriding the call to len with that object as the parameter. Same thing when you overload any other of those types of methods.